# Normal plus compact is Fredholm with index 0

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T, K \in B(H)$, $TT^{*} = T^{*}T$, $K$ compact. Why is $T+K$ Fredholm and $ind(T +K) = 0$? Is it even true? I have forgotten all I knew about Fredholm theory and I need that result  for proving some stuff about exact sequence of $C^{*}$-algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fred points out, this statement is not true in general.  The issue here is that there exist normal operators which are not Fredholm (the normal non-Fredholm operator $0$ being the given example).

What is true is that if $T$ is normal and Fredholm and $K$ is compact, then $T+K$ is Fredholm and $\operatorname{index}(T+K)=0$. This of course follows from the stability of Fredholm operators (and their indices) under compact perturbation, and the fact that normal Fredholm operators have index $0$.

Comment: Why are normal Fredholm operators have zero index?

Comment: @Vladislav Because $\ker T\oplus\operatorname{ran}T = H$.

Comment: @Vladislav Equivalently to amsmath's response,  it's easy to see that if $T$ is normal, then $\ker(T)=\ker(T^*)$.  Thus, if $T$ is normal and Fredholm, we have $$\operatorname{index}(T)=\dim\ker(T)-\dim\ker(T^*)=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. If $ \dim H = \infty$ and $T=0$, then the compact operator $T+K=K$ is not Fredholm, in general.

Comment: What if $T$ is nonzero?

Comment: @Vladislav Still not true:  let $\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$, and let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto the closed span of $\{e_{2n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$.  Then $P$ is normal, but not Fredholm.